# Why is my plt.savefig is not working?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a simple python code as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

"""
Here are the solutions and the plot.
"""

# Create the axis and plot.
plt.axis([0, 10, 0, 10])
axis_x = range(1, 11)
grd = [1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 4.1, 5.1, 6.1, 7.1, 8.1, 9.1, 10.1]
grd2 = [1.2, 2.2, 3.2, 4.2, 5.2, 6.2, 7.2, 8.2, 9.2, 10.2]
plt.plot(axis_x, grd, '-g', label='BR1')
plt.plot(axis_x, grd2, '-b', label='BR2')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.grid()
plt.show()

# Save the results vector to a text file.
np.savetxt('test.out', (grd, grd2))

# Save the figure as '.eps' file.
plt.savefig('expl.pdf', format='pdf', dpi=1200)
```

When I open the output files `expl.pdf` and/or `test.out` I find them blank and nothing in there. Why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

When you close the image displayed by `plt.show()`, the image is closed and freed from memory.

You should call `savefig` and `savetxt` before calling `show`.

Comment: Thanks. The plot is fine now. The `test.out` is still empty.

Comment: As the docs say "Because closing a figure window unregisters it from pyplot, you must call savefig before calling show if you wish to save the figure as well as view it." in the "Use show()" section of https://matplotlib.org/faq/howto_faq.html.

Answer (score 8):

I just ran into the same issue and the resolution was to put the savefig command before the `plt.show()` statement, but specify the filetype explicitly. Here is my code:

```
plt.suptitle("~~~~")
plt.title("~~~~")
ax = sns.boxplot(x=scores_df.score, y=scores_df.response)
plt.savefig("test.png", format="png") # specify filetype explicitly
plt.show()

plt.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

Your plot cannot be generated because you defined the list `axis_x` having only the length 9, while `grd` and `grd2` have the length equal to 10.
Just replace the definition of `axis_x` with:

`axis_x=range(1,11)`
and your plot will show up and it will be saved OK.

Comment: After posting this  answer the author modified `axis_x=range(1,11)` and now my answer looks like inappropriate :)